# Nodejs async overwriting values with knex

Tags: node.js, async.js, knex.js

I am trying to save multiple records in database using async but I always end up in one record overwriting others.

Here is my logic:

```
var deferred = q.defer();

var records = [{emp_id:1, got_bonus: true},{emp_id:2, got_bonus: false},{emp_id:3, got_bonus: true}];

async.each(records, function(record, next){
    saveRecord(record)
      .then(){
          next(null);
      });
}, function(){
    deferred.resolve();
});

function saveRecord(record){
   record['activity_type'] = 'bonus'; 
   db_module.save(record);
}

db_module.js
----------------
function saveRecord(record){
   var deferred = q.defer();

   checkDuplicate(record)
      .then(function(isDuplicate)){
          if(!isDuplicate){
              knex('employees').insert(record);

              deferred.resolve();
          }
      });
   }
}

function checkDuplicate(record){
   return knex('employees')
            .where({'emp_id': record['emp_id']})
            .then(function(rows){
                return rows && rows.length > 0;
            });
}
```

My problem is that even using async, the code is not waiting for first record to save and then saves next. The result of above code in database table is:

```
emp_id      got_bonus
-------     ----------
3            true
3            false
3            true
```

expected output is:

```
emp_id      got_bonus
-------     ----------
1            true
2            false
3            true
```

I tried to use async.waterfall but received the same error. I don't know how to use synchronize module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing **async.each** to **async.eachSeries** like this:

```
async.eachSeries(records, function(record, next){
  saveRecord(record)
    .then(){
      next(null);
    });
}, function(){
   deferred.resolve();
});
```

**eachSeries** is same as **each** but runs only a single async operation at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save your data by `one shot` -i.e

```
var records = [
    {emp_id:1, got_bonus: true},
    {emp_id:2, got_bonus: false},
    {emp_id:3, got_bonus: true}
];
var modifiedRecords = records.map((i) => {
    return Object.assign({}, i, {
       activity_type : 'bouns',
    })
});

knex('employees')
  .insert(modifiedRecords)
  .then(()=> {
       /// sent response
   })
```

Comment: Actually, the logic is divided into multiple layers